# Calling constructor of another class through Initialization list. Having problems

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, initializer-list

This is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base (int v, char z) {x=v;y=z;};
    int x;
    char y;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(int m, char n):q(m),s(n),base(q,s){};
    Base base;
    int q;
    char s;    
};

int main()
{
    Bar barObj(5,'h');    
    cout << barObj.base.x << barObj.base.y << endl;       
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting an output of `0`?
http://ideone.com/pf47j

Also, in general, what is the right method to create a member object in another class and call the constructor of that object, as was done above with object base of `class Base`, inside `class Bar`?

Comment: `Base base;` not `Base base (int v, char z);`. Read a proper book.

Comment: The code in your link is different to the code you have above

Comment: In addition to what Cat Plus Plus said, you need to use `m` and `n`.  `q` and `s` haven't been initialized before constructing `base`.

Comment: If you are using gcc, then try to compile with `-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`

Comment: You should really post the code that gives the problem not an old version of what you have

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The initialization order of data members follow their declaration order, not the order you list their initializer. Thus, `Bar::base` is always initialized before `Bar::q` and `Bar::s`.
As shown in http://ideone.com/M6iKR , for `Bar::Bar(int m, char n)`, initialize `base` using `m` and `n` works fine.

Comment: when you use `m,n` instead of `q,s`, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks I just moved the declaration of Bar::base below q and s.